# How to reference objects in a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: c++, oop, multidimensional-array, reference

I read that you can declare an aray of objects by this line

```
Enemy * d = new Enemy[2];
```

but when i tried to make a 2 dimensional array, there was an error where this cant be initialized. I also tried this

```
Enemy *enemies[6][2];
```

but i am not sure how to reference to each object in that array and and how to pass that reference to a function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a pointer to a pointer in order to make a jagged array.

```
Enemy** d = new Enemy*[6];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    d[i] = new Enemy[2];
```

If you plan on making a fixed size array, you can just create it the same as you would a normal array.

```
Enemy enemies[6][2];
```

You then just reference them using two indices.

```
enemies[2][1].roar();
```

Note: You will find that multi-dimensional arrays tend to lead to more headaches than they are worth. It is much cleaner to maintain a single dimension array and simply index it based on the number of rows and columns.

```
Enemy* enemies = new Enemy[rows * cols];

Enemy* getEnemy(size_t row, size_t col)
{
    return enemies + (row * cols + col);
}
```

Comment: and how do i pass that to a function if i create those arrays in my main?

Comment: You could just pass it as foo(Enemy** array); if you want the simple way.  There's a more complex way which allows you to maintain the type information for a statically sized array, but I wouldn't worry about that - a pointer to a pointer like the foo() above will be fine.

Comment: It depends upon how you made the array and how you are processing it. If you made a jagged array, you need to pass it as `Enemy**` and also pass the two dimensions. If you made a fixed size array, you need to declare at least one of the dimensions. `void kill(Enemy enemies[6][]);`

Comment: All those separate allocations hurt cache locality. Also, making them explicit also means the memory is hard to get rid of.

Comment: Agreed on the cache locality. I added a note to my answer above. Use single dimensional arrays where possible!

Comment: @celtschk You could allocate a single chunk and then use placement new to construct the objects... definitely not simple though.

Comment: I think I mistyped my function prototype earlier, but I cannot edit it. I think I meant to say `void kill(Enemy enemies[][2]);`

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to allocate a 2D array on the heap, this is how you do it:

```
Enemy (*enemies)[2] = new Enemy[6][2];
```

But it's a lot simpler without the indirection:

```
Enemy enemies[6][2];
```

Answer (score 1):

For C++ you should use std::vectors instead of C Arrays.

```
  std::vector<std::vector<Enemy> > d(6);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
       d[i].resize(2);

  //now d is ready to use
  d[1][2];
```

Comment: However with that method, your elements are not consecutive in memory (because the inner vectors all use separate allocations), and each access contains an extra redirection. Both may hurt your performance due to cache locality (or rather, the lack thereof). Instead, use a single vector with 2*6 elements, and access it using index arithmetic (preferably encapsulated in a nice class).

Comment: Yeah, I actually do not support this answer. You should only use vectors for very particular situations where you need the automated memory growth. Otherwise, you are best doing without all the excess cruft of STL just to allocate an array ONCE.

Answer (score 0):

You'd do

```
Enemy (*enemies)[2] = new Enemy[6][2];
```

That is, a pointer to arrays of 2 enemies.
Note that only the first array level can be made a pointer and therefore determined at run time.

Also note that your second definition creates an array of 6*2 pointers to enemies. Assuming you've initialized them all, you'd access them as `*enemies[j][k]`, or if each pointer itself points to an array, as `enemies[j][k][l]`.

Note that if you want to have both indices determined at run time, you should allocate one big array and use index arithmetics:

Enemy* enemies = new Enemy[6*2];
   // access the element (j,k)
   enemy[6*j+k].fight();

Of course, generally it is better to use a `vector<Enemy>` unless your class `Enemy` is not suitable for a vector, e.g. because it cannot be copied (resp. in C++11, moved). Also, when doing multidimensional arrays that way, ideally you should encapsulate the array and index logic in a class.